# HP linux printer driver filled my download folder with an update, is it okay to empty it?

Tags: printing, hplip

HPLIP installed an update, and filled the downloads folder with several hundred items while downloading the new version. Have the files been installed, or is it running some things from the Downloads folder? Might they be needed for a future update? Is it okay to delete them all?